# ios - UISearchDisplayDelegate doesn't search when search text is empty

Tags: iphone, ios, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uisearchbardelegate

I have a table view with a search bar, I want to search when the text is empty.

I want to display all the data, when the search text is empty (when the user doesn't type any search text)

**Note - Things work fine, when the search text is entered, the problem is ONLY when the search text is empty**

Unfortunately the contents of `self.arForSearch` array is not used when the search text is empty.

I even tried replacing the text with `"p"` and yet the data is not loaded.

**Question**
How can I display all the data, when the search string is not typed by the user ?

Code is pasted below:

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    if(searchString.length == 0)
    {
        searchString = @"p";
        NSLog(@"string was empty but was replaced by p");
    }

    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString];

    // Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
    return YES;
}

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)str{
    // for inCaseSensitive search
    str = [str uppercaseString];

    NSMutableArray *ar=[NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSDictionary *d in self.arForTable) {
        NSString *strOriginal = [d valueForKey:@"name"];
        // for inCaseSensitive search
        strOriginal = [strOriginal uppercaseString];

        if([strOriginal hasPrefix:str]) {
            [ar addObject:d];
        }
    }
    self.arForSearch=[NSArray arrayWithArray:ar];

    NSLog(@"self.arForSearch.count = %i", self.arForSearch.count);
}
```

Comment: yes I have set the delegate in the interface builder, it seems to work fine when the search text is entered.

Comment: Please post your code how to you filter if search text is not empty.

Comment: Pasted the code for reference in the original post. But the array populated (self.arForSearch) is not being displayed in the tableview

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)str{
// for inCaseSensitive search
str = [str uppercaseString];

if([str isEqualToString:@""] || str == nil)
{
     self.arForSearch=[NSArray arrayWithArray:self.arForTable];
}
else
{
    NSMutableArray *ar=[NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSDictionary *d in self.arForTable) {
         NSString *strOriginal = [d valueForKey:@"name"];
        // for inCaseSensitive search
        strOriginal = [strOriginal uppercaseString];

        if([strOriginal hasPrefix:str]) {
            [ar addObject:d];
        }
    }
    self.arForSearch=[NSArray arrayWithArray:ar];
}
NSLog(@"self.arForSearch.count = %i", self.arForSearch.count);

//updated code
[yourTable reloadData];
```

}

Just check for empty string and add all the elements from the self.arForTable to self.arForSearch.

Hope this helps...

updated....
then you might need to add the line [yourTable reloadData]; at the end which would refresh the table data

Comment: thanks Vimal, but that doesn't work. The problem the array is populated but then the table view doesn't reload / display them.

Answer (score 1):

I have written the following code in order to display the results when the search bar gets the focus and when it has no text.

NOTE: In my app, the search bar placeholder is equal to the last inserted search text, so you may need to adapt the code below.

```
//auxiliar function to force display of search results
-(void)forceDisplaySuggestionsForText:(NSString*)searchString {
    UISearchDisplayController *sdc = self.searchDisplayController;
    SEL sel = @selector(searchBar:textDidChange:);
    if([sdc respondsToSelector:sel]){
        UISearchBar *sb = sdc.searchBar;
        [sdc performSelector:sel withObject:sb withObject:searchString];
    }
}

- (void) searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
    controller.searchBar.text = controller.searchBar.placeholder;
    //this will force initial display of the search results
    [self performSelector:@selector(forceDisplaySuggestionsForText:) withObject:controller.searchBar.text afterDelay:0];
}

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)str {
    //this will force display of results when there is no text in search bar
    if([str length] == 0){
        [self performSelector:@selector(forceDisplaySuggestionsForText:) withObject:@" " afterDelay:0];
    }
    //the rest of the code for content filtering
    ...
}
```